# Forwarding an ip address to a server in another region on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, forwarding

I have been using a server in N. Virginia for a while with an elastic ip. Several applications that I wrote are connecting to that Ip for a database.

Now I need to move the server to Europe for some reason and will be given a different ip address.

Is there a way to forwward the old ip address to the new ip address automatically?

I don't think it's possible to associate an ip address from N. Virginia to a server in Europe, so what's the best way around this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't use an IP address to connect to resources in AWS for reasons like this. The only way this may work would be to maintain a small instance in Virginia with the elastic IP bound to it and redirect traffic to the instance in Europe with nginx or other proxy capable software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to set up DNS resolution using Route53 (set a low TTL), change your client configuration using the new DNS name, switch the db instance to the new region and update the DNS record making it point to the new EIP.

In AWS EIP addresses cannot be migrated among regions. Check this page out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: ok, so it's not possible unless I set up a proxy